# REST API standard to build URL - best match

Tags: rest

A situation where I want a URL for list of values for a filter a URL for best match out of them to be returned.
Example data is as follows

[image]

1. `/studentInformation?student=Albert&class=3&rollno=13&marks=24` will return 2 entries as no value is a value of interest to me
2. `/studentInformation/bestMatch?student=Albert&class=3&rollno=13&marks=24` will return 1 value which is the best match i.e entry no 3 (limiting to 1 would not find the best match)

what is the right way to form the URL for best match?

Comment: What is, in your opinion, wrong with the current URLs you gave (besides the spaces in them)?

Comment: thank you . spaced removed. bestMatch being an issue?

Comment: It is not clear what the issue is. Why are you asking if it is an issue? What is working not correctly? What do you want to achieve? Why ?

Comment: Basically I want to know what is the right way to build a URL in the above case. Is it right to use bestMatch in the URL parameter or should we use that in a query Parameter to indicate that additional logic should be executed to get the best match or should the base URL reflect it?

Comment: I do not see any extra logic (and I cannot determine the extra logic needed from your description).    From your description you are returning the records based on the inputparameters.

Comment: I also want to return null values as well along with valid matches. Albert with class null can also belong to class 3 so this value will be returned in first API . however, in the best match whatever matches everything is being returned

Comment: What are you using the paramater `class=3` (in `/studentInformation?student=Albert&class=3&rollno=13&marks=24`) when you are not interested in the class ?

Comment: REST doesn't care what the spelling used in the URI is. The URI itself is just used to request something. The thing that gives a client a clue on the purpose of that URI is encapsulated in link-relation names. This allows a server to change the form of the URI anytime it wants to by allowing clients to look them up easily, hence, a client is not interested in the spelling of the URI but in the content it might return upon requsting it. Answers to this are probably highly opinionated, hence voted to close this question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

REST doesn't have a standard for designing URI.  It just says that every resource should have one.

On the web, we have a standard that describes the production rules for URI ([RFC 3986](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3986)) and a standard that describes URI Templates ([RFC 6570](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc6570)), but neither of those get into the level of detail that you seem to be asking for.

And that's on purpose: URI on the web are a lot like variable names in a programming language; it's more generally useful to afford you the freedom to make local decisions about spelling conventions.

The machines don't care about semantic relationships between the spelling of the URI and the information of the resource, so you can choose any spelling that makes things better for people (where people here could be customers looking at the URI in their browser history, or pasting it into emails, or operators looking at URI in web logs, or writers trying to document your resource model, or even just the programmers trying to implement the API).